# While configuring sharepoint error has occured in configuration task 3 of 9 in configuration database

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

favorite

hi all,

I install sharepoint server 2010 in my system and then i run the configuration wizard, but an error is occoured in configuring database

Error:

An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException was thrown.Additional exception information: The specified User or domain group was not found

To diagnose the problem review the event log and configuration log file located at

c:\Program Files\Common Files\MicrosoftShared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS\PSCDiagnostics 2 22 2011 15 30 27 129 2015339452.log

Answer (score 1):

vijay,

Do exactly as the error message says.  Find the file referenced at the end of the message and look for the particular SPException log information.  If you find it and can't make sense of it, post the relevant parts here.  Make sure that the accounts you specified during the configuration wizard are configured properly for their role in the SharePoint farm.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you either have written the wrong username/password combo when running the wizard or you're machine is not connected to a domain.